# KeyListener, GLEventListener not working?

Tags: java, image, opengl, loading

i am doing project and I have problem probably with listeners. I think I implemented them correctly, but I am not sure. First time when application is started, image is loaded and displayed on canvas, but if I load another image using "L" key, it does nothing. Someone know what is causing this problem?

```
public class Listener extends JFrame implements GLEventListener, KeyListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int w, h;
    String path;
    BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
    GL2 gl;    
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);  
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });      
        canvas.addGLEventListener(new Listener());     
        canvas.addKeyListener(new Listener());

        FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, 60);
        animator.start();
    }

    public void loadImage(){
        try {
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Obrázky",
                    "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp", "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG", "BMP");
            fc.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
            fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            path = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();  
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(path));    

            w = bufferedImage.getWidth();
            h = bufferedImage.getHeight();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        loadImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(
                DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, w, h, 4, null);
        ComponentColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(
                ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), new int[] { 8, 8,
                        8, 8 }, true, false, ComponentColorModel.TRANSLUCENT,
                DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, false, null);

        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(bufferedImage, null, null);
        DataBufferByte dataBuf = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
        byte[] imageRGBA = dataBuf.getData();
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(imageRGBA);
        byteBuffer.position(0);
        byteBuffer.mark();

        gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();  
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrtho(0, w, h, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glDisable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);

        gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
        gl.glPixelStorei(GL.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_CLAMP);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_CLAMP);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexEnvf(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL.GL_REPLACE);
        gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL.GL_RGBA,
                GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);

        gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); 
        gl.glVertex2d(0, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); 
        gl.glVertex2d(w, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); 
        gl.glVertex2d(w, h);
        gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); 
        gl.glVertex2d(0, h);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glFlush();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_L)  
            loadImage();
    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {

    }

    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This code is not GL3 compliant, by the way. You never call `glGenTextures (...)` at any point, you just assume that you can bind a texture called **1** and have GL create it for you. Prior to GL3 this was acceptable, but compliant implementations are not supposed to work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to add the existing instance of `Listener` as a listener, but you are using a new instance instead. Try changing:

```
canvas.addKeyListener(new Listener());
```

to:

```
canvas.addKeyListener(this);
```

**EDIT**:

I assumed that the key listener did not work. But there is a problem with `GLEventListener` listener. The problem with image that is not displayed is that `GLEventListener` registered on yet another instance of `Listener`. The image is loaded, but `display()` is called on a different (not visible) frame. The first time it works because initial `loadImage();` is executed from `init()`.

You actually have three frames allocated and registered for different tasks. Try to get rid of a static frame to simplify things. For example add a constructor:

```
public Listener() {
    GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
    GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
    GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);  
    setSize(300, 300);
    add(canvas);
    setVisible(true);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    canvas.addGLEventListener(this);     
    canvas.addKeyListener(this);

    FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, 60);
    animator.start();
}
```

Refactor the `main` to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Listener();
}
```

And get rid of a static frame:

```
//static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Comment: Sadly this isnt possible, because in java I can not use this in static methods (static context). 'frame.addKeyListener(this)' is working but as soon as I click into window - frame will lost focus (focus now has canvas) and is no longer listening.

Comment: @Hefatel You can drop the `static` if you want, see if last edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at just this code out of context, the main error that I see is that its a JFrame, which all thought it may be fine in most cases, for some reason, in certain cases of personal experience, I have noticed that it can cause listeners not to function for some reason or another. Being as you don't use any JComponents, you should be fine converting to a normal Frame, which my just be a simple solution to your problem.

This is incredibly likely if there is not output from the try catch in loadIamge(), being as that measn that is was likeyl never called, a good thing to test this may just be a out.println("Do I get called?"); inside the method. its usually a good practice for debugging.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, changing from JFrame to Frame was the solution.